# How to analyse an electronic circuit in a more intuitive way?

Tags: electronics

I want to understand how to analyse complex circuits (for example with diodes, transistors,  amplifiers...etc) in a more intuitive way. My question is not about application of the basic principles of electronics, but about reaching the intellectual prespective of my professor, who apparently assume I would understand his "linguistic" analysis of the circuit, while what I only learnt is the robotic mathematical analysis of circuits. I think its about reaching a new abstract level of thinking, in which new but larger elements of electronics emerges. I am not writing here to get an answer. I am asking for books, from which I can reach that level of thinking.

Comment: Welcome to engineering SE.  You will achieve this with good understanding of the electronic fundamentals and practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you maybe suggest rescources, where I can efficiently achieve that?

Comment: Try books on circuit *design*, not analysis. Learn how to recognize common "building blocks" in circuits and how they work, without needing to analyze all the details inside each block.

Comment: I suggest sharing an example circuit you are having concerns as part of the question, than we can help you achieve your goal.

Comment: I'm don't think books that help to reach a certain level of thinking exist, it mostly comes down to practice, practie, practice - in this case designing and analyzing circuits. What looks like intuition is often memory.

Comment: That's just called familiarity with the topic. Same as how a musician or athlete first has to think about every little motion when training and over time it just becomes inate and they no longer have to think about it so systematically.

Comment: EE here. I often visualize electricity like a fluid. Capacitors are tanks with head pressure, diodes are check valves, batteries are pumps. Resistors are flow restrictions. Inductors are coils where the fluid builds up inertia. Mosfets are fluid operated valves, etc. I don't know of any books discussing these types of analogies unfortunately.